# Any possible solution to list all google doc add-ons?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

We are making a suggestion and security reference of add-ons scripts to the college. Is there a possible way (api?) to get a full list of Docs/Sheets/Forms add-ons, with the rating and user number information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API for fetching the listings in the Add-on store.